# Wordpress - Include Pages in Template-file?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I´m having a template and the content of the Footer is hardcoded in footer.php.
Now I want to create a wordpress page and include this in footer.php:

```
<footer>
include page-id "5"
</footer>
```

Is this possible?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). Basic usage would look something like:

```
<footer>

<?php
    $page_5 = get_post(5); 
    $title = $page_5->post_title;

    echo $title;

    // etc...
?>

</footer>
```

You can't actually `include` page 5, because there isn't an actual file to include. You need to retrieve the post object from the database and `echo` it in the format you desire.